We’ll decide on the team as and when we qualify

We’ll decide on the team as and when we qualify.

I found this sentence in a dictionary I use.
What's the meaning of the sentence?
In what context, would this sentence be used?
The team exists already and choose the team among a number of teams? Or we have to organize a team?

Were you looking up as and when? Definitions are fairly clear - at the time when (used to refer to an uncertain future event) - "they deal with an issue as and when it rears its head" (Oxford Languages). Presumably the sentence refers to a sports club hoping to qualify for a tournament (to be considered good enough to take part).

Please provide us with more detail. What were you looking up? which dictionary(s) were you using? What don't you understand about the quoted text?

It's legalistic language close in structure to  "if and when we qualify", but substituting "as" for "if", removing any doubt about whether they will qualify, "as" making it more of a foregone conclusion.
We will decide on who is selected to be on the team when we are officially approved [by some entity that qualifies (or disqualifies) applicants].
The lawyer for a rich man who wants to create a new NFL football team in a city that lacks one might say such a thing to a sports reporter who asks "Who will be on the team?" before it has even been approved by the NFL.  Or the rich man himself might say it, if he  often deals with lawyers and has picked up some of their talk.

The team exists already and choose the team among a number of teams? Or we have to organize a team?

It could fit a number of circumstances. It could be used in the early stages when a new team is being proposed for inclusion in a league.  It could also be used of a team that exists formally, like a country's Olympic team, but if that team has been suspended for some reason,  and needs to re-qualify for admission into a particular Olympic games, perhaps because a previous team had been taking banned substances.  The team members won't be decided upon until after the team qualifies.
